# Dynamic content data attribute not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery

on the #board div I'm appending 5 buttons with 5 different data-id.

After I press the buttons I'm changing data-id to data-id="new id". But when I'm clicking again I still get the old id.

http://jsfiddle.net/6L0bv9Lv/1/

```
$('#board').on('click', 'button', function() {   
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('.ids').text(id);

    $(this).attr('data-id', 'new id');    
});
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not how you update a `data-` attribute via jQuery:

```
$(this).data("id", "new id");
```

is the proper way. The library will only consult the attribute *once*. After that, the "id" property is in the map that jQuery maintains internally. By using the `.data()` API to update the value, you update that map.

If you want for some reason to update the DOM too, you're free to do that, but jQuery won't.

Comment: Thanks, works with the data('id... but I want to update the DOM too, http://jsfiddle.net/6L0bv9Lv/2/ - here works to update the data-id but for some reasons the button dosent become red.

Comment: @Marius as I wrote above, jQuery will not update the DOM for you. [Here is an update to your jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/8c0zn7pb/) Personally I would use a class for that sort of style information and not a `data-` attribute, because `data-` attributes (to me) don't seem to be about presentation. However as you can see in the fiddle I linked, it will work.

Comment: thanks, the problem is that the new id is generate randomly. I will follow your advice and use classes instead of data-attributes.